# What sort of flute do "native american flute" musicians use?

Tags: flute

What sort of [flute](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=native+american+flute&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) does "native american flute music" use? Ballpark. I would like to get a traditional sounding (and looking) flute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types of flutes differ by tribe, but they all generally tend to be in the same style and shape as a recorder...

[image: Native American Flutes]

[From the Wiki:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_American_flute)

> The instrument is known by many names.[3] Some of the reasons for the
>   variety of names include: the varied uses of the instrument (e.g.
>   courting), the wide dispersal of the instrument across language groups
>   and geographic regions, legal statutes (see the Indian Arts And Crafts
>   Act), and the Native American name controversy.
>
> Native American names for the flute include:
>
> ```
> Cheyenne: tâhpeno
> Chippewa: bĭbĭ'gwûn[4]
> Dakota: ćotaŋke[5]
> Kiowa: do'mba'[6]
> Lakota: Šiyótȟaŋka[7]
> Opata: bícusirina (Teguima language)[8]
> Unami: achipiquon (Lenape)[9]
> Zuni: Tchá-he-he-lon-ne, lit. 'sacred warbling flute'[10]
> ```
>
> Alternative English-language names include: American Indian courting
>   flute,[11] courting flute,[12] Grandfather's flute,[13] Indian
>   flute,[14] love flute,[15] Native American courting flute,[16] Native
>   American love flute,[17] Native American style flute (see the Indian
>   Arts And Crafts Act), North American flute,[18] Plains flute,[19] and
>   Plains Indian courting flute.[20]
>
> Names in other languages include:
>
> ```
> Austro-Bavarian: Indianafletn
> Dutch: Indiaans-Amerikaanse fluit
> Esperanto: indiĝena amerikano fluto
> French: Siyotanka
> German: Indianerflöte
> Hawaiian: Papa ʻAmelika ʻohe kani
> Japanese: ネイティブアメリカンフルート
> Korean: 인디언 피리
> Polish: Flet indiański
> Russian: Пимак, romanized: pimak
> ```

Comment: I don’t think that’s accurate - recorders don’t feature the intermediate chamber to collect the breath and cause the distinctive vibration of. They may superficially look like recorders (or more like wooden folk whistles) but the sound mechanism is very different.

Comment: Yes. I am not saying that they are recorders... aesthetically similar, 'style and shape' referring to the fact that they are tubular woodwinds played more like a recorder than an edge-blown aerophone (as the modern flute.)